# One form two action

Tags: forms, cakephp

Hi i have a few form fields i want the on click of button a the control to be sent to action 1 but 
on click of button 2 it has to be sent to action 2. Currently i am using js to change the form action dynamically on click. but is there any other solution. I cant do the checking after submit in a same method thet have to be two different  methods.

The 2 buttons in this case are view(html data needs to be displayed) and download(same data as csv file). I am using cakephp 1.2 but i feel this is more of a generic problem

Comment: Stop. Don't try this. Have your (server side) controller forward the request internally based on the data submitted (only the activated button will be successful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 has a [formaction](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/13-formaction.html) attribute for this

```
<form action="/url" id="myForm">
     <input type="submit" value="save1" formAction="/url1" />
     <input type="submit" value="save2" formAction="/url2" />
</form>
```

Here is a fallback if you need it.

```
if (!('formAction' in document.createElement('input'))){
 $('form').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function (e) {
    var attr = this.getAttribute('formAction');

    if (attr) {
        this.action = attr; //Set the form's action to formAction
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One form can only have one action. This is a limitation of HTML. To work around it on the client-side, you need Javascript.

It sounds like the better idea would be to give each submit button a distinctive `name` and `value`. This will be submitted like other form elements, so you can detect in the Controller which button was clicked. From there it should only be a matter of switching some View logic in the controller between normal output and download.

Comment: here is an example http://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/dev/app_controller.php#L579

Comment: thanks but can you paste the exact code or the line no's that i need to look at anyways +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

I found out there are few solutions

1. **Regular JavaScript** to change th form action on click of the buttons
2. **AJAX** to send the data to two separate actions on click of separate buttons
3. As suggested by **deceze** to do the processing on server side(which was not easily possible in my case)