# CakePHP 1 form 2 buttons to different action

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I'm working in an application that can edit html content. This is a form that put file content to textarea (file get content) for edit. Have 1 button to send textarea to action 'edit' and write file (file put content)

**My problem:**

I want a second button called 'Preview' that send data to action 'preview' and open preview view with textdata content submitted.

How could I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is only based on the controllers and view, try this:

In view:

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Send', array('class' => 'btntext_send', 'div' => false, 'name' => 'send'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Preview', array('class' => 'btntext_send', 'div' => false, 'name' => 'preview'));
```

In controller:

```
public function yourfunction(){
  if($this->request->data['submit'] == 'send')){

// Your code

  }elseif($this->request->data['submit'] == 'preview')){

// your code

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use JQuery to bind a specific behavior to a specific button ?

```
$( '#button1' ).click(function() {
            //do stuff
        })

$( '#button2' ).click(function() {
            //do other stuff
        })
```

Comment: how set cakephp controller and action?

Comment: Maybe this can help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282254/multiple-submit-buttons-in-cakephp-form

Comment: glad this could help you